# Postgres nesting functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a multitude of functions which insert different data into several tables.
In some cases, for all functions, a staff ID column will need to be populated.
Since all of the data inserting functions return the ID of the inserted row, I could do set_staff_id(staff_id, insert_data1(...));
Instead of adding an optional staff_id argument to all data inserting functions, and coppying the set staff_id code too.

I'm trying to avoid code duplication, but wonder if this is the correct aproach.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres allows you to use `insert` inside a CTE.  So, this formulation might help:

```
with s as (
      insert into staff(. . .)
          values (. . .)
          returning *
     ),
     t1 as (
      insert into t1(staffid, . . . )
          select s.staffid, . . . 
          from s
     )
insert into t2(staffid, . . . )
    select s.staffid, . . . 
    from s;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I haven't used CTEs at all before.